# How do I change the way the RAD Studio (2010 and later) IDE formats my code?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, code-formatting

How do I configure the RAD Studio IDE to format my code with `begin` on either the same or next line when I use the `Format Source` option?

One of the most commonly debated preferences is the position of `begin` - on the same line or a line of its own. How do you set Delphi to format your source with `begin` on one line or the other in Delphi XE2? This is referring to when you go to `Edit` > `Format Source`

Comment: +1. Nice question and answer combination - upvote for each of them.

Comment: PS - Any input on this setting in prior versions of RAD Studio?

Comment: There is no "prior version setting". The code formatter was added in RAD Studio XE, IIRC (may have been 2010, though). Before that, you had to use a third-party solution like the JEDI code formatter or the one in GExperts - see [Delphi code formatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402737/delphi-code-formatter) for info.

Comment: Just checked - it was added in 2010, and it's in the same exact place and has (AFAICT) option settings.

Comment: @Warren - except the info applies to D2010 as well, and not only to Delphi but to C++ Builder (which is why I removed Delphi in the first place). :-)

Comment: The question talks about Begin though. So if you want it to be general, then please make the question also clearly about C++ and Delphi formatting.  The answer is about Delphi begin/end formatting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am answering this question Q&A style.

1. Go to `Tools` > `Options`
2. Find the `Formatter` section in the tree on the left
3. Inside that node, select `Delphi` > `Line Breaks`
4. Locate the section on the right labeled `Insert line breaks for Begin and Single instructions`
5. Inside here, find the setting labeled `Line breaks before Begin in control statements`
6. Switch this setting between `Yes` or `No` depending on your preference.

[image: Switch between Yes and No to change how begin is positioned]

`Yes` will produce this:

```
if (Foo = Bar) then
begin

end;
```

`No` will produce this:

```
if (Foo = Bar) then begin

end;
```

By default, this setting is set to `Yes` which means when you use `Format Source`, it will always bring `begin` to the next line.

There are many settings in this section which can define how `Format Source` will treat your code. This option is available in at least RAD Studio 2010 and above. Not sure of which exact editions.

Note: `Ctrl` + `D` is a keyboard shortcut to format your source, a quicker alternative.

Comment: Also note that Ctrl-D acts on the current selection only if there is any.

Comment: @UweRaabe Took me 4 years to respond to your comment, but Yes, that is true - and by default, there's a confirmation dialog which comes up regarding this, which has a "Don't show me again" option (of some sort, I'm not looking at it now). Once you tell it that, you never see that dialog again, it just proceeds with formatting. I don't like disabling dialogs like that, because in case I accidentally hit the wrong keyboard shortcut, I don't want my source (selected or all) to change from how I wrote it. Not arguing, just an an observation :-)