# How to make RAD Studio format case statements appropriately?

Tags: delphi, code-formatting, delphi-xe8

This is a follow-up to [a prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859066/how-do-i-change-the-way-the-rad-studio-2010-and-later-ide-formats-my-code) I asked a while back.

To summarize, I prefer to have `begin` statements show on the same line, rather than the next line. However, as a result of this, `case` statements do not format very friendly with the default settings:

```
case SomeEnum of
  seOne: begin

    end;
  seTwo: begin

    end;
  seThree:
    ;
  seFour:
    DoSomething;
end;
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it format like so instead:

```
case SomeEnum of
  seOne: begin

  end;
  seTwo: begin

  end;
  seThree: ;
  seFour: DoSomething;
end;
```

However, I cannot find the appropriate options to make this change.

How do I make case statements format as shown above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current setup needs two modifications. Set "indent case contents" to false in "indentation" options and "line breaks before single instructions in control statements" to 'no' in "line breaks" options.