# Shortcut to Indent the code in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-2007

Is there a way to indent the code in Delphi? I have to work on a program that has thousands of lines of code. **In eclipse** which I had worked before, I have used  **CTRL + SHIFT + F** to format all code by formatting tabs/whitespaces and also divide code lines in a way that it is visible without horizontal scroll. Is there a way to do the same in Delphi?

Comment: You can use the tab key to indent, or `Ctrl + K + I` / `Ctrl + K + U`

Comment: This may come in handy in the future: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402737/delphi-code-formatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a way to format the code in the whole unit with indentation.

This is not included in the regular IDE. But there is a code formatter contained in an 'experimental' version of the GExperts:

http://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to format the code in the whole unit with indentation.

`Menu -> Edit -> Format Source`

[image: Menu -> Edit -> Format Source]

You can also use `Ctrl + K + I` and `Ctrl + K + U` to indent current or selected lines.

Comment: Is that option available in delphi 2007 also ? I am not able to see in my IDE

Comment: It is included since D2010.

Comment: @delsql you can try CnPack: http://www.cnpack.org It contains a tool for code formatting.

Comment: [delphi shortcuts](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the code formatter in GExperts, which mjn already mentioned, there is also one in [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Activate CnPack -> Editor Enhancements -> Tab/ShiftTab to indent/unindent
2. Press Alt then use the mouse to select a **block** text you want to indent. Note: with Alt pressed you can select multiple lines of code starting at a random column (opposite of what would happen if you don't press Alt, when your selection will be applied of full rows).
3. Press Tab to move/indent the selected block of text.

My life would be sad without Alt+Block select then Tab.