# Where does this `else` statement end?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, delphi-7

Trying to convert this bit of `Delphi` code to `C#` and I'm confused on where the following `else` part of the `if/else` statement actually ends. Below is the exact formatting of the code:

```
 try
   Root:=ExtractFileRoot(FileName);
   ErrorStr:=ExtractFileRoot(FileName)+' invalid name';
   if not GetNextNumericSegment(Root,Segment) then exit;  
   if length(Segment) = 4 then
   begin
      Year:=StrToInt(Segment);
      GetnextNumericSegment(Root,Segment)
   end
   else // Where does this else statement end?
       Year:=Defaultyear;
    ErrorStr:=ExtractFileRoot(FileName)+' invalid';
   if Length(Segment) <> 3 then exit;
   Jday:=StrToInt(Segment);
    ErrorStr:=ExtractFileRoot(FileName)+' Bad File';
   if not GetNextNumericSegment(Root,Segment) then exit;  // bad Time of day
   GetTimeFromFileName:=EncodeDate(Year,1,1)+Jday-1+
                        EncodeTime(StrToInt(Copy(Segment,1,2)),StrToInt(Copy(Segment,3,2)),StrToInt(Copy(Segment,5,2)),0);
 except
       GetTimeFromFileName:=0;
 end;
```

I know you don't have to use a begin/end, but everything I've seen so far in this code has used it. I also read that you don't need a `;` in the `if` part of the statement and that the first `;` after the `else` is the end of the `else`.

My guess is that everything under the `else` and up to the `except` is part of the `else` statement.

Note: This would be easy if I could actually debug, but unfortunately I'm just being given snippets of code and functions to convert with no real context.

Comment: `else` will end after this statement: `Year:=Defaultyear;`

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why that is? Is it because of the formatting or something else?

Comment: Try reading the documentation for the language. There's really no substitute for the understanding that will bring.

Comment: No. Formatting is completely ignored by the Delphi compiler. If a block is not bordered by the `begin/end` keywords, `if/else` clause will always be applied to its first statement.

Comment: @pfinferno for the same reason it would end exactly where it would in C/C++/C# - that is the very next statement that is controlled by else-clause. With that controlled statement the else-clause is complete and over. There is no difference between Pascal/Delphi and C/C++/C# there

Comment: I've just always used brackets to group the `else` clause together since I started coding, even if it was one line of code after the `else`.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28221465/62576) will help somewhat.

Comment: @pfinferno: Yes, it may be that you did that, but in C-like languages as well as in Pascal/Delphi, it is not required. And the author of this piece of code didn't.

Comment: @pfinferno - if your code is all as badly formatted as the above sample, I would recommend using a code formatter. Older versions of Delphi don't have one built in, but there are several third party free one available - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402737/delphi-code-formatter

Comment: Thanks Gerry! It's not my code. It was written 14+ years ago and I'm not even sure the original person that wrote it is still around. But it is all formatted weird with zero comments :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest reading the documents, [If Statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#If_Statements).

After `else` follows a statement. Each statement (structured or not) can be ended by a semicolon separator `;`.

The statement can be [compound](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Compound_Statements). In that case it is enclosed within a `begin/end` construct.

In your case the `else` statements ends with `Year := DefaultYear;`

---

I recommend to always use a ´begin/end´ pair, even if the statement is a single line. The code is more readable and if you would add a line later, less mistakes would follow.

Comment: FWIW, the `;` is a separator rather than a terminator. Statements do not necessarily have to be followed by a `;`.

Comment: +1 for answering the way you have.  Just one picky point - the semi-colon after `Year := DefaultYear` isn't part of the else statement, it as, as @DavidHeffernan says, a separator, that may not be needed, depending on whether another statement follows.

Comment: @MartynA, Yes leaving out the semi-colon is possible if no other statement follows, but more of a nuisance if statements are added later.

Comment: "It is a good coding standard to always use a ´begin/end´ pair" says who? I think this is opinion/flavor based. Look at the Delphi source code.

Comment: @kobik, I have seen too many mistakes and misunderstandinga about this. Using begin/end is what I recommend :-)

Comment: I personally find code that uses more begin/end pairs than necessary harder to read. I personally omit them if the statement can be reduced to a single one. But I agree with kobik that this is a preference. I understand the argument that it is good to always use begin/end, and why, but I think it makes code far more verbose than necessary.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, you can add this quote to your forum postscript answers: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." --Brian Kernighan

Comment: @kobik: *Look at the Delphi source code* is often a very bad idea. It's full of inconsistencies and poor programming habits, as well as badly written code in some cases.

Comment: @KenWhite, I agree that there are inconsistencies. but still for me, Delphi source code is the best convention. that's why I commented that this is a preference. I hardly think `if (a = 1) then
  b := 2
else
  b := 3;` should have a `begin/end` blocks.

Answer (score 6):

An `else` branch contains

- the next single statement (a method call, an assignment etc.)

  ```
  if x=5 then
    DoThis
  else
    DoThat; // <-- This is the complete else branch
  ```
- or the block marked with `begin` and `end`

  ```
  if x=5 then
    DoThis
  else
  begin // <-- Here starts the else branch
    DoThat; 
    DoSomethingElse; 
  end; // <-- Here ends the else branch
  ```

So in your case this is the entire `else` branch.

```
Year:=Defaultyear;
```

*Side note*: 
Formatting doesn't matter here. It's for readability purpose only. Only `begin` and `end` do change the amount of statements inside an `else` branch.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I was confused is because in another snippet I was given, there were several lines formatted the same amount of spaces as the next statement under the `else`. Wasn't sure if it was meant to have a `begin/end` or whoever wrote it just indented the lines by accident.

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful to always use Begin/End regardless of how many statements there are. For example;

```
If A = 1 then
    Begin
      // Every line here executes if A = 1
      ShowMessage('A does in fact equal 1');
      ShowMessage('These messages can be annoying')
    end 
      else
    Being
      // Everything here executes if A doesn't equal 1
      ShowMessage('A was not equal to 1');
      ShowMessage('This is still an annoying message') 
    End;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to " reading the documentation" mentioned above, and if you need a visual tool that help you track if/else pairs and other things in Delphi 7, I advise you install Castalia tools. It will be of great help to you.