# Delphi 7 Line Indentation option?

Tags: delphi-7

I have received 10 PAS files. All the lines in these 10 files starts in column 1. NO indentation at all.
Biggest file is 2548 lines.

Now I wonder: Is there an OPTION in my Delphi 7 Enterprise (running on XP sp 3) to automate that indentation to increase readability (at least for me):

IF not I plan to scan through the files and when BEGIN, THEN, ELSE, CASE, END   etc. (where indentation will be natural) is met, I will (if necessary)  do a manually indentation. (But it is smarter letting Delphi do it).

Comment: See the utilities mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402761)

Comment: You certainly don't need to get delphi to do this. Any tool will do. These are just text files after all.

Comment: Recent version of Delphi have a code formater. You have a zillion options to make the code like you want, we the indentation you want, alignments and many more. You could install the free community edition just to get the code formater. The code is not changed, just his layout, so no problem going back to Delphi 7.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CnPack
http://www.cnpack.org/showlist.php?id=39&lang=en

it has (among a lot of features) a Code Formatting Wizard and some other nifty features to enchance the IDE

Comment: Thanks, I will download and try it.

Comment: @KristianSander Have you done so inbetween?